# Firebase realtime database does not return last cached copy when went offline

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I establish some connection to Firebase ref, code is as follows:

```
var userRef: DatabaseReference? {
   guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return nil }
   return databaseRef.child("users").child(uid)
}
```

and I read data as follows:

```
if let userRefHandle = userRefHandle {
    userRef?.removeObserver(withHandle: userRefHandle)
}

userRefHandle = userRef?.observe(.value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
        log("User entry is empty, setting up account as new", level: .dataService)
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            self.setupNewAccount(user: user)
        }
        return
    }
    
    self.updateDataFromFirebase(value: value)
    
}, withCancel: { error in
    log(error)
})
```

When I'm online, everything goes fine. When I go offline (for example by entering Airplane mode) - at app relaunch I don't get last cached response - I simply get nothing.

Error handler is not getting called, setting up verbose firebase logging doesn't bring any other info except for we don't have internet connection - nothing. So neither successful handler nor failure handler are getting called

Do you have any clue what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable disk persistence as shown here? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence

Comment: Yes, sure, in AppDelegate init method right after FirebaseApp.configure() I call Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've tried everything possible. Probably our app uses Firebase Storage, with some significant space to sync, and it reaches some caching limit? Or RTDB works independently on Storage? Actually, I have so few instruments to try so it makes me absolutely desperate

Comment: The caches of various Firebase products don't influence each other. I'm actually not sure what could be causing this, so you might want to see if [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_:) gives any clue.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen here is log with wifi enabled https://justpaste.it/9b52e and here is with airplane mode on https://justpaste.it/8cp44 . As per I can see, NSKeyedUnarchiver is known issue, posted by Google guys to Apple guys. NSURLErrorDomain is self-explanatory, we have no internet. There is some cache-related message "No cached config result" in remote config message, but nothing about RTDB. Please, I've spent two nights digging into this, if you see in logs anything that may help...

Comment: I have one assumption - may it be the case - look at the Database Reference, it's based on another Google Firebase example, it's "databaseRef.child("users").child(uid)". So it points to a child users, which contains thousands of entries, each equal to a user's UID. Maybe it tries to cache the entire "databaseRef.child("users")"? And reaches some limit (I saw 10mb, 100mb in FB DB code)? And doesn't fire any log message. It's just a guess, only Google dev may know the truth... thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The Realtime Database SDK caches only data you already read when the client is online. It does not try to cache any additional data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank for the details, am I right in following assumptons:
- I simply subscribe to entity change via "userRefHandle = userRef?.observe(.value) { [weak self] (snapshot) in". When online - it returns data from online DB, when offline - from offline DB

- Firebase purchase plan, DB online settings, etc can't affect offline caching options

- All I need to do to enable cache is what you've mentioned - isPersistenceEnabled of DB singleton and probably scoresRef.keepSynced(true) as mentioned in docs - magic will happen under hood?

Comment: There's no magic. Enabling disk persistence stores the values that you read in a disk cache, and reads them back from there when the app starts. Calling `keepSynced(true)` on a reference/query puts an empty listener on that reference/query, so that the data is always kept up to date in the app (and the cache if that is enabled).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen in my case the reference subscription never gets fired in offline. Could you point how do I debug this issue? Where this cache in sandbox is located? Maybe I can debug some entry point and find out why it's not red and populated

Comment: The persistent cache is stored in level DB on iOS, but that's about all I know. Since the SDK is open-source though, this may help: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Persistence

Comment: I think the question needs more details. Saying *I simply get nothing* doesn't help us to understand *where* you're getting nothing. Are you getting nothing here `guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?` and it's returning nil, which is not "nothing". Or are you getting nothing here `userRefHandle = userRef?.observe(.value)`?  I noticed you don't have an error handler - that may be helpful as if the `.observe` is returning an error, it will just silently fail and you will never know why.

Comment: @Jay By mentioning I get nothing - I mean that the closure isn't get called. uid is not nil, handle is some integer.

Comment: @Jay following your advice I've added "withCancel:" closure, which isn't getting called either. So yes, it's silently falling without any interesting error messages - as cache never existed. Look at my logs above - that's all I have (with all possible debugging levels of FB enabled). Everything else just going fine when offline - but the block NEVER gets called in offline, even if previously app was working fine in online

Comment: @Jay So to summarize - I've got nothing indicating there's some error. I have correct setup. I have success. I have error handler. Neither is getting called when in offline

Comment: Can you please update the question to include a complete code example with your updated code?

Comment: @Jay sure, here's an update - the complete code I use. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: @Jay Any clues what could go wrong? I still have no idea on how to make it work.

Comment: TBH, there are so many places in the code where it could fail without you knowing, it's hard to know where to start. Doing things like `{ return nil }` or a standalone `return` will make things really hard to track down. This `guard let self = self else { return }` is trouble as well. You mentioned Storage in a comment and I don't believe storage uses offline persistence at all - you have to manage that. I think the place to start is to add a breakpoint here `if let userRefHandle = userRefHandle` and step through the code, examining the vars and code execution until something goes wrong.

Comment: @Jay thank you for the response, 1) self of course exists at the moment of call 2) userRefHandle is not nil - it returns a value, the observer code is never get called. If storage is a completely separate code from RTDB - it's not a point to discuss. Well, when I get back to this issue I will dig more deeply and return with issue, maybe it's some rare firebase bug that your team will fix? Who knows, anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) Sure. then why have that code as it's extraneous 2) if the handle is populated then the function has executed. How do you know the observer code is never called? Did you add a line of code directly following the firebase call `print("HELLO!")` and then add a breakpoint to it? I mentioned storage as you mentioned it in your above comment - just wanted to make sure you knew it was not cached.